# Bug introduced on Chrome v51.0.2704.79 m impossible to empty large select

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 64; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
function emptySelect(){
 $("#test").empty(); 
}
$(function(){
 for ( i=0; i< 1e4; i++){
  $("#test").append("<option name='"+i+"'>"+makeid()+"</option>");
 }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="test"></select><hr/>
<input type="button" value="empty select" onclick="emptySelect()">
</body>
```

( or check code here : http://jsbin.com/bowasuneje/edit?html,output )

Works on Chrome version 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit) ( and I assume previous versions ).

But since 51.0.2704.79 m ( most recent version ) the code is not working anymore. And chrome **crashes**

This code insert 10 000 option elements inside a select. When the button is clicked the select should be emptied. This use JQuery, but using code like :

```
mySelect = document.getElementById("test");
while ( mySelect.firstChild ){
    mySelect.removeChild( mySelect.firstChild );
}
```

does not work either.

Anyone can reproduce this issue ? Any ideas for nice workaround ?

Thank you,

Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's troubling.  In Chrome 51.0.2704.79 m, it crashes with as few as 2,000 option elements.

If you have that many options, a select element may not be the best choice.  But that's no reason for Chrome to crash.

A workaround is to detach the select element before emptying it, then prepend it back to the body:

```
function emptySelect() {
  $("#test")
    .detach()
    .empty()
    .prependTo('body');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function makeid() {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

      for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;
    }

    function emptySelect() {
      $("#test")
        .detach()
        .empty()
        .prependTo('body');
    }
    $(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < 1e4; i++) {
        $("#test").append("<option name='" + i + "'>" + makeid() + "</option>");
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="test"></select>
  <hr/>
  <input type="button" value="empty select" onclick="emptySelect()">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, we have also experienced the same thing. Is this filed as a bug anywhere with the Chrome dev team that you know of?

Comment: @JamieQuint, not that I'm aware of.